# How to do toast notification on the top right corner using bootstap 5.2 and angular 14

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, toast

I wanted to do toast notifications using bootstrap 5.2 and angular 14.

Toast notification should have a separate component with custom styles, with toast.services.ts

I can call the toast component, from any other component for any onClick events, It should appear.

Like -

**Success -**

```
this.toastService.showSuccessToast('Success toast title', 'This is a success toast message.');
```

**Warning -**

```
  this.toastService.showWarningToast('Warning toast title', 'This is a warning toast message.');
```

**Error -**

```
  this.toastService.showErrorToast('Error toast title', 'This is an error toast message.');
```

**Info -**

```
this.toastService.showInfoToast('Info toast title', 'This is an info toast message.');
```

Bootstrap link - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/toasts/

**In short how to create a custom notification service using angular 14.**

Note -

If it is not a bootstrap, I can be custom as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check this: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/toast/overview

Answer (score 0):

You can styple toast notification by defining it's position. like this -

```html
 <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;">
```

Full examples are here - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/toasts/

Comment: I know this. What I want, create a custom notification service using angular 14.